# PATH vs symlink subl: command not found

Tags: bash, path, sublimetext3

When I `echo $PATH` on my mac I see:

```
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
```

Running `code` for opening a project with the vscode editor works, however `subl` gets the error `-bash: subl: command not found`. I noticed online a lot of people suggest symlink to `usr/local/bin` however I don't understand why that is necessary if it is already in my PATH.

If I `cd /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin` I see `subl` exists there.

If I run the following in my terminal `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` then sublime opens. However if I try to run subl directly from inside that bin then it does not open.

`subl` inside bin has the following permissions: `-rwxr-xr-`

I'm adding this to my path by adding this to my `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/"
```

I'm not really sure why it's not opening with the command `subl` and I don't understand why I would need to link if it is in my PATH. I'd prefer to fix it with a solution I understand.

Comment: I don't know mac. Are the escapes for the spaces actually necessary on the path? I can see they are useful on the command-line, but! perhaps this is why people prefer to use symlinks? :-)

Comment: oh! actually I do need to escape when testing the `export PATH=...` in terminal but I do not need the escapes in `.bashrc`! Strange that vscode path also has escapes in bashrc but that works both with and without escapes

Comment: @Turnipdabeet You are currently escaping twice. Quotes don't define a string; they implicitly escape every character contained in the quotes. `"foo"` is equivlaent to `\f\o\o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping the spaces twice. Quotes implicitly escape every character they contain, including the `\` you use to escape the space. Either of the following would work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/"
```

Which you choose is a matter of preference.

Note that you can also drop the `export`. You export *names*, not values, so once `PATH` has been exported, it stays exported. (In fact, `PATH` is exported by default, because you inherit it from the process that started your shell.)